# How could I protect my paypal form

Tags: php, ajax, api, paypal

I'm new to the paypal API, I read an article today that says : It's very simple for a bad guy to change the value of inputs in the paypal form (like the amount).

So instead of putting my code in the html markup, I decided to bring it via the ajax as the following :

```
<div id="result"></div>


$.post({'action.php', {}, function(data)
{
   $('#result').html(data);

}, , 'html');
```

in my page action.php, I put this simple code :

```
<?php
     echo '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="99">';
?>
```

**My question is : In this case, could bad folks change the value of this input ?**

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain where exactly this "bad guy" comes into things? As someone filling in the form? As someone else? If someone else, where is he coming from?

Comment: try firebug or webdeveloper tool

Comment: You mean it's *within the page*? Sure. You don't even have to save it and modify it; they've got wiretap software like Live HTTP Headers (browser addon) and WireShark that can do it for them. I'm not real familiar with Paypal anything, but I'd be surprised if you weren't indemnified or held harmless if it were a real problem; who in their right mind would *want* to submit any amount of their business payments through a system a bystander could hack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course they could.

Using the web developer tools that come with the browser, or with firebug, they can change values of hidden fields or of JavaScript values *before* the AJAX call.

You are adding a very thin layer of obfuscation that anyone with web development experience can easily get through.